# Validación de JTextxfield. Permitir una sola vez un caracter especifico dentro del campo

Tags: java, validación, jtextfield

Buen dia. Estoy trabajando sobre la validacion de un JTextField, donde requiero que el campo solo reciba 1 vez un caracter en especifico. Ej:

1223-2344
1232--3434

No debe repetirse mas de una vez el guion. Tengo este código que funciona para validar solo letras en el campo pero no he podido encontrar la forma de adaptarlo para lo que necesito

```
    char c = evt.getKeyChar();
    
    if (Character.isDigit(c)) {

        getToolkit().beep();

        evt.consume();

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Solo se permiten letras");

    }
```

Les agradezco su colaboración. Gracias

Comment: Te recomiendo que investigues sobre las [`regex`](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_regex.asp) (expresiones regulares, en inglés **Reg**ular **Ex**pression) en java.

Comment: ¿Qué pasaría con `1-2-3`?

Comment: No debería permitirlo, solo debe poder ingresarse un solo guion, en eso estoy trabajando

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He realizado un ejemplo para introducir un código con formato `xxxxx-xx` (x = número). Nota que he utilizado el diseñador gráfico de Netbeans 11.

Primero, añadimos un listener para el objeto `Document` del JTextField (en este ejemplo, la variable de tipo JTextField se llama `textCodigo`). He puesto el listener en el constructor de la clase `MyForm` (que extiende de `javax.swing.JFrame`).

Este listener se encargará de analizar el texto del JTextField. Si el texto tienen una rayita, entonces la variable privada `codigoConRayita` será `true`. En otro caso, `false`.

```java
public MyForm() {
        initComponents();
        textCodigo.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new javax.swing.event.DocumentListener() {
            @Override
            public void insertUpdate(javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent e) {
                hacerAccion();
            }

            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent e) {
                hacerAccion();
            }

            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent e) {
                hacerAccion();
            }
            
            private void hacerAccion(){
                codigoConRayita = textCodigo.getText().contains("-");
            }
        });
    }
```

Ahora creamos otro listener para el evento `KeyTyped` del JTextField. Este listener mostrará una notificación si el texto ya tiene una rayita y evitará su inserción mediante `evt.consume()`.

```java
 private void textCodigoKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                    
        if ('-' == evt.getKeyChar() && codigoConRayita) {
            evt.consume();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Solo se permite una rayita.");
        }
    }
```

Hasta aquí ya tenemos la lógica suficiente para invalidar más de una rayita. Ahora creamos un botón para validar todo el texto. La variable `buttonValidar` de tipo `JButton` tiene el listener para el evento `Action`, que utiliza el método `validarCodigo`, que a su vez utiliza el API Regex de Java (paquete `java.util.regex`).

```java
 private void buttonValidarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
        if(validarCodigo()){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Código tiene formato correcto.");
        }else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Código tiene MAL formato.");
        }
    }

private boolean validarCodigo() {
        String text = textCodigo.getText();
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9]{5}-[1-3]{2}");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
        return matcher.matches();
    }
```

El resultado se muestra en esta animación:

[image: resultado final del ejemplo]

Comment: Muchas gracias @nonameyet por tu colaboración. Tu respuesta funciona perfectamente, gracias de nuevo

Comment: Uhmm, `String` proporciona el metodo `matches` que, considero, encaja perfecto para manejar esa validación eficientemente vía expresion regular. `textField.getText().matches("[0-9]+-[0-9]+")`

Comment: Utilicé una expresión regular para este ejemplo. Puedes usar la expresión más adecuada a tu problema. Si necesitas más ayuda sobre Regex, te recomiendo practicar con los tutoriales de Java (en inglés) y probar tus expresiones en Regex101.com